# Consulta mysql que agrupa as distâncias percorridas a cada dia

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá,
Iniciei uma query a partir de um banco de dados mysql onde a distancia de cada deslocamento de um motorista está salvo juntamente com o horário:

```
DATE_FORMAT(l.dateGenerated,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS Day ,
d.name AS Conductor,
ROUND((l.odometer/1000),3) AS Route

from location l 
left join device d on (d.id = l.deviceId)
```

```
| Day              | Conductor | Routes |
|------------------|-----------|--------|
| 05/07/2019 19:12 | PAULO     | 0      |
| 05/07/2019 19:14 | MARCOS    | 0      |
| 05/07/2019 19:14 | MARCOS    | 0,488  |
| 05/07/2019 19:16 | MARCOS    | 0,651  |
| 05/07/2019 19:16 | PAULO     | 0,533  |
| 05/07/2019 19:16 | MARCOS    | 0,703  |
| 05/07/2019 19:16 | PAULO     | 0,571  |
| 05/07/2019 19:17 | MARCOS    | 0,755  |
| 05/07/2019 19:17 | PAULO     | 0,602  |
| 05/07/2019 19:20 | PAULO     | 0,757  |
| 06/07/2019 08:10 | MARCOS    | 0,807  |
| 06/07/2019 08:11 | MARCOS    | 0,911  |
| 06/07/2019 08:12 | MARCOS    | 1,015  |
| 06/07/2019 08:13 | MARCOS    | 1,067  |
| 06/07/2019 08:15 | MARCOS    | 1,223  |
| 06/07/2019 08:16 | PAULO     | 0,791  |
| 06/07/2019 08:16 | PAULO     | 0,833  |
| 06/07/2019 08:19 | PAULO     | 1,01   |
| 06/07/2019 08:20 | PAULO     | 1,063  |
| 06/07/2019 19:16 | PAULO     | 1,114  |
| 06/07/2019 19:17 | PAULO     | 1,165  |
```

Mas o que preciso exatamente e não estou conseguindo é calcular a distância diária percorrida por cada motorista, imaginei pegar a última medição do odômetro de cada dia e subtrair pela primeira medição, para gerar algo assim:

```
| Day    | Conductor | Traveled Day |
|--------|-----------|--------------|
| 05/jul | Paulo     | 0,757        |
| 05/jul | Marcos    | 0,755        |
| 06/jul | Paulo     | 0,408        |
| 06/jul | Marcos    | 0,468        |
```

Algum "Hero" poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se você explicar como chegou aos resultados apresentados em Traveled Day talvez consigamos ajuda-lo.,

Comment: Conseguir o Traveled Day é meu objetivo aqui, o exemplo acima é o desejado que não consegui trazer.

Comment: É só somar todos os Routes de cada dia para cada conductor? Eu imagino que você consiga explicar o cálculo que espera que seja feito para se chegar ao resultado desejado, senão será impossível adivinharmos e tentarmos ajuda-lo.

Comment: @anonimo na verdade não é só somar. Você precisa somar o do dia e descontar o do dia anterior

Comment: Qual a versão do `MySQL`?

Comment: Sua solução parece ideal  @Sorack! Infelizmente estou rodando a versão 5.7.26-0 ubuntu 0.19.04.1

Comment: @AcimarRocha indiquei na minha resposta também a query referente a versões anteriores

Answer (score 1):

Simplifiquei a sua tabela da seguinte forma apenas para facilitar a resolução:

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE location(
  dateGenerated DATETIME,
  Conductor     VARCHAR(100),
  odometer      NUMERIC(15, 3)
);

INSERT INTO location(dateGenerated, Conductor, odometer)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:12', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:14', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:14', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.488),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.651),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.533),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.703),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.571),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:17', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.755),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:17', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.602),
       (STR_TO_DATE('05/07/2019 19:20', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.757),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.807),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:11', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 0.911),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:12', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 1.015),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:13', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 1.067),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:15', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MARCOS' , 1.223),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.791),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 0.833),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:19', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 1.01),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 08:20', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 1.063),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 19:16', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 1.114),
       (STR_TO_DATE('06/07/2019 19:17', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PAULO' , 1.165);
```

---

Depois criei uma `CTE` (apenas para `MySQL` a partir da `v8.0`) com o valor máximo diário. Com os valores separados por dia, subtraí o somatório das localizações anterior para chegar no valor percorrido por dia:

**Query(v8.0)**

```
WITH daily AS (
  SELECT DATE(l.dateGenerated) AS dateGenerated,
         l.Conductor,
         MAX(odometer) AS odometer
    FROM location l
   GROUP BY DATE(l.dateGenerated),
            l.Conductor
)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.dateGenerated,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateGenerated,
       d.Conductor,
       d.odometer - COALESCE((SELECT MAX(odometer)
                                FROM location l
                               WHERE l.Conductor = d.Conductor
                                 AND l.dateGenerated < d.dateGenerated), 0) AS Route
  FROM daily d
 ORDER BY d.Conductor,
          d.dateGenerated;
```

---

Para versões anteriores você pode substituir o `WITH` por uma `subquery` no `FROM`.

**Query(Versões anteriores à 8.0)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.dateGenerated,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateGenerated,
       d.Conductor,
       d.odometer - COALESCE((SELECT MAX(odometer)
                                FROM location l
                               WHERE l.Conductor = d.Conductor
                                 AND l.dateGenerated < d.dateGenerated), 0) AS Route
  FROM (SELECT DATE(l.dateGenerated) AS dateGenerated,
               l.Conductor,
               MAX(odometer) AS odometer
          FROM location l
         GROUP BY DATE(l.dateGenerated),
            l.Conductor) d
 ORDER BY d.Conductor,
          d.dateGenerated
```

---

**Resultando em**

```
| dateGenerated | Route | Conductor |
| ------------- | ----- | --------- |
| 05/07/2019    | 0.755 | MARCOS    |
| 06/07/2019    | 0.468 | MARCOS    |
| 05/07/2019    | 0.757 | PAULO     |
| 06/07/2019    | 0.408 | PAULO     |
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4kdJVXye6A1TGAUWFTTi5A/0)

Comment: Vc entendeu exatamente o que preciso! Só deu erro pela falta de suporte ao CTE. E não posso atualizar este servidor no momento por estar em produção.

Comment: Teria uma forma de fazer essas sub-consultas sem o uso da cláusula WITH? Com join talvez?

Comment: @AcimarRocha já está adicionado a resposta. É a segunda query

Comment: Agora vi a versão sem com subquery. Vou testar aqui e já falo!

Comment: para simplificar tentei usar as ids dos condutores sem o join na tabela devices, assim modifiquei o mínimo possível a sua consulta. Se verificar apenas o condutor de id 2, os resultados vieram estranhos, com os totais ficando negativos:

dateGenerated;deviceid;Route
15/07/2019;2;-509094.28125
14/07/2019;2;-690920.578125
13/07/2019;2;-756583.375
12/07/2019;2;7978.1875
11/07/2019;2;116861.0625
10/07/2019;2;146732.5

Comment: @AcimarRocha infelizmente sem as estruturas e dados reais das suas tabelas não consigo produzir seu resultado

Comment: a estrutura desses dados utiizados são duas tabelas, basicamente:

CREATE TABLE `device` (
 `id` INT(11) ,
 `name` VARCHAR(255)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE `location` (
 `id` INT(11),
 `deviceId` INT(11) ,
 `odometer` FLOAT ,
 `dateGenerated` TIMESTAMP 
 
);

Comment: @AcimarRocha mesmo assim não vejo nada errado com a `query`. Monte um `fiddle` com os seus dados para que eu possa aplicar a `query` nele

Comment: Parece certo sim! Estava achando estranho dar um número negativo. Descobri erro nos dados, o odometro zerou.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rzbMh3r6JgxPwn9HgEvDas/0

Comment: @AcimarRocha então, aí que está o problema. Se os dados não são consistentes não tem resposta que resolva seu problema. A solução acima resolve se, e somente se, os dados estiverem corretos

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que esse `odometer` é a distância, você pode somar isso e agrupar por motorista:

```
SELECT DATE(l.dateGenerated) AS Day,
d.name AS Conductor,
ROUND((sum(l.odometer)/1000),3) AS Route

from location l 
left join device d on (d.id = l.deviceId)
GROUP BY Day, Conductor
```

Comment: Acho que não é isso que o OP quer. Ele quer a distância percorrida no dia. Você precisa descontar o do dia anterior.

Comment: Ahhh, acho que entendi. Então o campo `odometro` na verdade é o valor acumulado de cada usuário?

Comment: Acredito que sim

Comment: Exato Ronaldo! Da forma que vc sugeriu traz corretamente a distância de cada motorista sendo acumulada a cada dia. Se conseguir a (ultima distancia do dia) - (a primeira do dia) temos o que percorreu a cada dia. Complicado rs!